# Is there a difference between using "this" pointer and not using it?

Tags: c++, performance, this

Does using "this" pointer adds another operation to the program at runtime?

Just to give an example to explain the question better:

```
class C
{
public:
    void set_x(int val){ x = val; }
    void set_this_x(int val){ this->x = val; }

private:
    int x;
};
```

Does the function "C::set_x()", during runtime, performs 1 less operation than "C::set_this_x()" ?

Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is no difference between the two member functions. It has to be, since this is what the C++ Standard (ISO/IEC 14882:2003) has to say:

> **9.3.1 Nonstatic member functions [class.mfct.nonstatic]**
>
> *2.* When an `id-expression` (5.1) that is not part of a class member
>   access syntax (5.2.5) and not used to form a pointer to member (5.3.1)
>   is used in the body of a nonstatic member function of class `X` or
>   used in the `mem-initializer` for a constructor of class `X`, if name
>   lookup (3.4.1) resolves the name in the `id-expression` to a nonstatic
>   nontype member of class `X` or of a base class of `X`, the
>   `id-expression` is transformed into a class member access expression
>   (5.2.5) using `(*this)` (9.3.2) as the postfix-expression to the left
>   of the `.` operator. The member name then refers to the member of the
>   object for which the function is called.
>
> **5.2.5 Class member access [expr.ref]**
>
> *3.* If `E1` has the type “pointer to class `X`,” then the expression
>   `E1->E2` is converted to the equivalent form `(*(E1)).E2;` ...

So that means the following code:

```
class C
{
public:
    void set_x(int val) { x = val; }
    void set_this_x(int val) { this->x = val; }
private:
    int x;
};
```

would've been transformed to the following code according to 9.3.1/2 and 5.2.5/3:

```
class C
{
public:
    void set_x(int val)      { (*this).x = val; }   // as per 9.3.1/2
    void set_this_x(int val) { (*(this)).x = val; } // as per 5.2.5/3
private:
    int x;
};
```

To show that there really is no difference, at least for one compiler, here's a side-by-side comparison of the disassembly of the `C::set_x()` and `C::set_this_x()` function the VC++ compiler emits with optimizations disabled (`/Od`):

```
  void set_x(int val){ x = val; }      void set_this_x(int val){ this->x = val; }
push      ebp                        push      ebp
mov       ebp,esp                    mov       ebp,esp
sub       esp,0CCh                   sub       esp,0CCh
push      ebx                        push      ebx
push      esi                        push      esi
push      edi                        push      edi
push      ecx                        push      ecx
lea       edi,[ebp-0CCh]             lea       edi,[ebp-0CCh]
mov       ecx,33h                    mov       ecx,33h
mov       eax,0CCCCCCCCh             mov       eax,0CCCCCCCCh
rep stos  dword ptr es:[edi]         rep stos  dword ptr es:[edi]
pop       ecx                        pop       ecx
mov       dword ptr [ebp-8],ecx      mov       dword ptr [ebp-8],ecx
mov       eax,dword ptr [this]       mov       eax,dword ptr [this]
mov       ecx,dword ptr [val]        mov       ecx,dword ptr [val]
mov       dword ptr [eax],ecx        mov       dword ptr [eax],ecx
pop       edi                        pop       edi
pop       esi                        pop       esi
pop       ebx                        pop       ebx
mov       esp,ebp                    mov       esp,ebp
pop       ebp                        pop       ebp
ret       4                          ret       4
```

Note that the compiler produces *the exact same assembly* for both member functions.

Answer (score 9):

No, it doesn't make a runtime difference, it's just syntax. The `this` pointer is still accessed in the first function, it's only specified implicitly instead of explicitly.

By the way, this smells like a premature optimization - write clean code first, fast code later.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! :-)
I'm not making any optimizations yet, just thinking of places what can be done when the time comes. I've been burned once from premature optimization, had enough of that :-).

Answer (score 8):

The `this->member` syntax is required if you inherit from a class template:

```
template<typename T>
class Base
{
protected:
    T x;
};

template<typename T>
class Derived : Base<T>
{
public:
    void whatever()
    {
        T a = x;         // error
        T b = this->x;   // ok
    }
};
```

Comment: Something is needed to get past the problem that `x` is a nondependent name, but that something is not necessarily `this->x`. One could use `using Base<int>::x` inside the class declaration or use `int b = Base<int>::x;` in the function `Derived::whatever`.

Comment: This example is wrong because `Derived` doesn't have a dependent base class.

Comment: @Johannes: Better? If not, please fix.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no difference.
when you refer a member directly, the compiler actually derefers it through the `this`.

Answer (score 3):

It's the same. However, "this" can be used to disambiguate in certain cases.

```
class C
{
public:
    void set_x(int x){ x = x; } // does nothing
    void set_this_x(int x){ this->x = x; } // sets the variable

private:
    int x;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

No.

If you stumbled over that expression in someone's code, it's probably originated in something like this:

```
struct A
{
    int x;

    void set_X(int x)
    {
        this->x = x;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

No difference, the compiler already automatically generates code for this->  While it is superfluous syntax, there are two good reasons to use it:

- using an editor that supports auto-completion.  When you type "this->", the editor pops up a tool window that presents a list of class members to choose from.  This can speed up typing and helps avoid silly compile errors due to typing mistakes.
- it helps avoiding having to come up with artificial argument names.  You can give the argument the same name as the class member: void set_x(int x) { this->x = x; }.

Answer (score 2):

That you can say `foo` instead of `this->foo` is just syntactic sugar. There is no difference in the compiled code. Like all syntactic sugar, a small handful decry it but most love it. To see where you stand on the issue, try using a language like perl or python that doesn't provide this syntactic sugar. Python code is peppered with `self.foo`; in perl OO code you'll see `self->foo` all over the place. It can be a bit distracting.

Answer (score 1):

One of the times it matters is when you are giving a local variable the same name as a class member. For example:

```
class Example {

public:

    int something();
    int somethingElse();

}


int Example::somethingElse() {
    int something = something(); // ERROR
    int something = this->something(); // OK
    // ...
}
```

Comment: There are places in template programming where you need to resort to using `this` as well. Grep for `this->` in the C++ standard library and you will see that the code is peppered with `this->`.